# Bootstrapping failed when deploying iOS app to external testers via cloud platform

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing, app-distribution

I am generating an iOS build for distribution to external testers in services such as AWS Device Farm or Applause. The build is being generated with `app-store` distribution, since I don't know what devices the app will run on (thus I can't use `ad-hoc` distribution). These external testing platforms re-sign the app as part of their distribution process to testers, as seen [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/developerguide/skip-app-re-signing-on-private-devices.html) or [here](https://help.applause.com/kb/how-applause-works-with-apple-developer-licenses/).

The build generates an IPA successfully. This one can't be installed on a local device though, since it is intended for App Store Connect (and it does work in TestFlight BTW). When I upload this IPA to one of these external platforms, then it crashes on launch.

This is the error message:

```
"Bootstrapping failed for <FBApplicationProcess: 0x116773190; application<my.bundle.identifier>:-1> with error: <NSError: 0x282b9bf30; domain: RBSRequestErrorDomain; code: 5; reason: \"The launchd job couldn't be started.\"> {",
```

I am using an account registered in the Apple Developer Program and signing certificates are up to date (I can distribute without problems via TestFlight).

How can I run the app successfully for manual testing on these cloud platforms?

Comment: Having the same problem here too. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, I did not find a solution for this @extensa5620.